# String in a text file containing a string in C++

Tags: c++, string, search, line, contain

here's a part from my code

```
string word;
cin >> word;
string keyword;
while (file >> keyword && keyword != word){}
```

This searches for a word in a file and if it finds that word (keyword) then it starts a string from there later. It's working perfectly at the moment. My problem is that when the line is

```
"Julia","2 Om.","KA","1 Om. 4:2"
```

if I enter word Julia I can not find it and use it for my purposes (just FYI I'm counting it). It works if I search for "Julia","2 since this is where space comes in.

I'd like to know how can I change line

```
while (file >> keyword && keyword != word){}
```

so I can see when the text/string CONTAINS that string since at the moment it only finds and accepts it if I enter the WHOLE string perfectly.

EDIT: Also what I have found this far is only strstr, strtok, strcmp. But these fit more with printf than with cout.

Comment: So if your enter `Julia`, you want it to stop with `keyword` as `"Julia","2`? Or do you want it to stop with `keyword` as `"Julia"`?

Comment: No, if I enter Julia I want it to find Julia - at the moment it does not find it, it is able to find "Julia","2 since that is the whole part but I do not need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're extracting strings, which by default will extract up until the next space. So at the first iteration, `keyword` is `"Julia","2`. If you want to extract everything separated by commas, I suggest using `std::getline` with `,` as the delimeter:

```
while (std::getline(file, keyword, ','))
```

This will look through all of the quoted strings. Now you can use `std::string::find` to determine if the input `word` is found within that quoted string:

```
while (std::getline(file, keyword, ',') &&
       keyword.find(word) == std::string::npos)
```

Now this will loop through each quoted string until it gets to the one that contains `word`.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm trying to get it working at the moment. Also 2. Om is not supposed to be keyword, if I understood you from your last comment. My input is Julia and my output is actually

int cnt = 1+ count( istream_iterator<string>(file), istream_iterator<string>(), word);
cout << word << " appears in text " << cnt << " times";

as you can see I'm writing Julia and then want the wordcount of just Julia but it doesn't find Julia if it's surrounded by other characters.

Comment: So I actually don't want the loop to end there since I need to count all Julia's in a file and there are loads of these names in my file.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I am able to find Julia in that file but it only counts it once and stops, in the line where the name is first found. Since there are like 10 Julia lines in that file (20 000 lines, all different names), I still need for it to loop, any idea how could I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use methods from std::string like `find`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
// ...
std::string keyword;
std::string word;

getline(file, keyword);
do
{
    std::cin >> word;
}
while (keyword.find(word) == std::string::npos);
```

Comment: Although this is what I thought they were describing at first, I don't think it's what they want. They don't want `"Julia","2` to match as `Julia`.

Comment: @sftrabbit He wants to find Julia even if it's surrounded by other characters, and this finds Julia even if it's surrounded by other characters.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant Patashu. Sorry for confusion and thank you for your answers :) I'll try to get it working now.

Comment: @JackLongen I still don't think this is what you want. You will still be extracting `"Julia","2` and not `"Julia"`. The keyword `2 Om.` will not be found using this method at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method of istream to get a whole line instead of just a single "word":

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/

Then use strstr, to find the location of a string (like Julia) in a string (the line of the file):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strstr/

Comment: Thank you, strstr fits more with printf though. I'll try to use std::string find method.

Comment: @Jack Longen I also prefer Julien's answer